# Plone message facility to tell users about maintenance downtime

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

How would I tell the (anonymous, or authenticated) users of my Plone site about a scheduled maintenance downtime?

I think of a "flash message" (like those "Your changes have been saved" messages) which is shown to every user exactly once (until explicitly receipted) before the downtime; after the downtime there should be *another* message (perhaps shown only to those who saw the pre-downtime message), *or no message at all* (but of course not the pre-downtime message anymore).

Which Plone product or builtin facility would I use for this purpose?

Comment: We're using https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.globalstatusmessage The package simply puts a persistent flash message in the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the proposed suggestions you may also have a look at:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.notices
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.messagesviewlet/

Answer (score 2):

Use Products.ContentWellPortlets and add a static-portlet above the content.

Comment: I found it [at Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.ContentWellPortlets); it seems to me that this product has another focus.

Comment: Yes, all the product does is to allow to assign portlets also in header- and footer-areas, not only in side-columns. You can simply use a static portlet and insert the wanted HTML, or you can use any other available kind of portlet suiting your needs, e.g. mirrow documents containing the message, and only show them after pub-date is arrived and before exp-date passed by (name of the addon doing that is sth with 'page' and 'portlets', I'd need to look it up).